# Inkscape won't "Take [properties] from selection" for the Box tool

Tags: inkscape

I have a new installation of Inkscape 1.2 on a Windows 10 system.

Every time I draw a box, it has no outline; I have to turn on the Stroke. So I'd like to make that default.

I select a box which has the stroke I want, and go to the Properties with Shift-Ctrl-P, and select the <s>Box</s><sup>1</sup> Rectangle tool under Shapes. When I click on the "Take from Selection" button, it doesn't "take" the Stroke setting: it stays `none`.

If I go to the Pen tool instead and click on its "Take from Selection", **that** works: the Stroke changes, and then I see that various kinds of curves use a line which matches my original box.

Why doesn't the <s>Box</s> Rectangle tool like settings taken from an object of its kind?

---

1. I miswrote "Box" in the first draft of the question, but the remarks apply to the Shapes->Rectangle item in the Tools defaults panel.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It's likely because 3D boxes created with that tool are actually made up of separate objects. There's several sets of attributes that would apply to each face of the box. And so "Take from selection" doesn't really seem to work with that tool as far as I can tell.  Perhaps that option shouldn't really be displayed at all.  A potential bug? Perhaps you should report it.

Comment: @BillyKerr I think I'm giving up on that dumpster fire. Inkscape used to be merely hard to use. Now I can't even get it to remember stroke settings for a new box.

Comment: That's a shame.  I like Inkscape a lot. All vector image editors can be a bit of a pain as they are complex applications. Also Inkscape has had quite a revamp in recent years, so some things have changed position, and some tool behaviours have changed too. As for the 3D box tool, I tend to keep it set up to "Use tool's own style" in preferences. That way it's less troublesome, and changes to fills or strokes can be made afterwards.

Comment: You even can select all your boxes after you've finished making them, and change the strokes in one go.

Comment: @BillyKerr I'm not using any 3D boxes. Just 2D. So the Box tool in Properties is actually the 3D Box tool? In that case the Pen tool should determine the properties for all 2D work? When I change its properties, different kinds of path objects use those properties, but not the 2D box.

Comment: Do you mean the Rectangle Tool which is 2D,  or the 3D Box tool.  There is no "Box tool" in Inkscape.  The "take from selection" button works perfectly fine with the Rectangle tool.  You need to specifically select the Rectangle tool options in Preferences to change how the tool works.  The Pen Tool(aka Bézier) is a separate tool with its own preferences. It's not linked to any other tool preferences.

Comment: @BillyKerr I'm going through the steps now. Indeed, under Shapes there is a Rectangle. That's what I was using, not Box (and not 3D Box at the end of the list). I have a 2D rectangle: transparent with a black border. It is selected. When I click on the "Take from Selection" button of the Rectangle tool, it stays at "Stroke: none".  What's worse, it's now gotten into a mode where all rectangles I make are invisible: no stroke, no fill.  It looks as if the tool isn't making rectangles, but Select All reveals their existence.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. It works fine for me. Sorry. I'm on Inkscape 1.2.2. - Win 11, but it also works fine on a Win 10 machine I have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146945/discussion-between-billy-kerr-and-kaz).

Comment: @BillyKerr  The version string here is `Inkscape 1.2.2 (732a01da63, 2022-12-09)`.  Anyway, I don't think I should be going into control panels to set basic tool defaults, even if it works.

Answer (score 0):

this usaly happens  when you updated from older version and Preferences form old version are not compatible with new version. I recommend Reseting your preferences .

1. Edit-preferences-system - Reset preferences
2. Restart Inkscape